# Как реализовать оповещение chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

В background.js код проверяет элемент

```js
var online = document.getElementById("online");
if (online.innerHTML == "online") {
  //тут должно быть оповещение 
};
```

Пытался реализовать по примерам,ничего не получилось,да и гуглить трудно(выдаёт всякий бред не по теме).
Пытался читать документацию через переводчик(с английским всё сложно),тоже мало чего получилось.

Может подскажите,какой код выведет мне оповещение? +ещё хотелось бы увеличить циферку в иконке расширения. И что нужно будет добавить в manifest.json. Ну или информацию,как это реализовать на русском.

Comment: Если ваш background.js действительно именно тот, как называется, то ему не доступен никакой документ. Вернее есть бакграунд документ который вы в браузере не увидите и никакие оповешения никуда не попадут. Через средства разработчкика в принципе можно добраться до этого окна но смысла особого нет. Что бы работать с документом, открытым в текущей вкладке вам нужен content скрипт, он отдельно описывается в манифесте.

Comment: @Mike но мне нужно,чтобы работа была с документом НЕ открытым во вкладке.

То есть оповещения можно сделать только,когда документ открыт во вкладке?

Comment: @Mike и да про бэкграунд документ я знаю,туда я гружу сам документ,потом оттуда получаю нужное мне.

Единственное,что я смог,так это проиграть звук через background.js.
Но хотелось бы какое-нибудь видимое оповещение.

Comment: Если обычным alert - то да, алерты в вкладке показываются и доступны только контенту. Можете конечно popup окно открыть и в нем написать, но опять же это не бакграунд. Вы можете зайти в меню расширений, включить вверху галочку "режим разработчика" и около вашего расширения нажать "фоновая страница", вот тогда у вас откроется отдельное окно с вашим background.js, и там будет обычная консоль, из которой видно все что в нем и ваш скрипт запросто на нее может выводить с помощью console.log()

Comment: @Mike это я тоже знаю,про консоль. В popup у меня предается полностью весь результат(300 элементов проверяются каждые 10 сек потом идёт в popup),просто это ждать долго и  я опаздываю иногда. 
Я не имел ввиду alert.Хочется как в gmail например или же есть расширения для вк,которые оповещают о новом сообщении,даже если вк не открыт. Выходит маленькое окошечко справа снизу. Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: @Mike
Вот я сделал скриншот.
[Кликабельно](http://fastpic.ru/view/77/2016/0524/22cf95d2f9cb9f63ef12219fd0eecbd5.png.html)

Comment: это еще актуально?

Comment: @UserName уже нет,я реализовал,просто читал какие-то старые способы,поэтому и не получалось.

Comment: @ThreegunD, в таком случае добавте свою реализацию в качестве ответа.